How can I prove $d(A,B)=0 \Rightarrow \partial A \cap \partial B \neq \emptyset$?
The problem is the following:

Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space, and $A$, $B \subseteq X$ disjoint sets such that
$d(A,B):=inf\{d(a,b):a \in A, b \in B\} = 0$
Prove that $\partial A \cap \partial B \neq \emptyset$

This was my reasoning: if $d(A,B)=0$ then $\exists a_n \subseteq A, b_n \subseteq B$ such that $D_n := \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} d(a_n,b_n)=0$
As $X$ is compact, and $(a_n) \subseteq A \subseteq X$, then $\exists a_{n_k} \rightarrow a \in X$ (Is this $a$ particularly in $\overline{A}$ ?)
As $D_{n_k}$ is a subsequence of $D_n$, it tends to 0, but as $d(a,b_{n_k}) \leq d(a,a_{n_k})+d(a_{n_k},b_{n_k}) \rightarrow 0$, then $b_{n_k} \rightarrow a$
(which, if my suspicion is right, is in $\overline{A}$)
Then $a \in \overline{A} \cap \overline{B}$, and therefore $\overline{A} \cap \overline{B} \neq \emptyset$
I have two doubts:

Is it ok to imply that $a\in \overline{A}$ or $a \in \overline{B}$?(same argument for both)
Can I show that $\overline{A} \cap \overline{B} \neq \emptyset \Rightarrow \partial A \cap \partial B \neq \emptyset$ ?


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

$A \cap B \neq \emptyset $ implies what?  $\partial A \cap \partial B$ is not a statement.

You are right, I'm sorry, I meant $\partial A \cap \partial B \neq \emptyset$, but I will change the problem anyway, I think I have to reformulate it, adding more context

If $a$ is an interior point of $A$ then $b_{n_k}$ would be in $A \cap B$ for $k$ sufficiently large.


is in general false, but here it is true because $A,B$ are disjoint.


Note that $\text{Cl} A$, being a closed subspace of a compact space, is compact. So, a sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^+}$ of elements of $A \subseteq \text{Cl} A$ has a subsequence $(a_{n_k})_{k \in \mathbb{Z}^+}$ that converges to some $a \in \text{Cl} A$.
Then, you showed that $d (a, b_{n_k}) \to 0$, giving $(b_{n_k}) \to a$. Now, each sequence element $b_n \in B$, and thus $b_n \in \text{Cl} B$. Since $\text{Cl} B$ is indeed closed, it follows that $a \in \text {Cl} B$.
You thus showed the existence of $a \in \text{Cl} A \cap \text{Cl} B$. Now, it was given that $A \cap B = \emptyset$, so clearly $\text{Int} A \cap \text{Int} B = \emptyset$. Note that there cannot be any element in $\text{Int} A \cap \text{Bd} B$ or $\text{Int} B \cap \text{Bd} A$. (For example, if $a' \in \text{Int} A \cap \text{Bd} B$, then since $a' \in \text{Cl} B$, every neighborhood of $a'$, including $\text{Int} A$, intersects $B$, which contradicts the hypothesis that $A, B$ are disjoint.) Therefore, it must be that $a \in \text{Bd} A \cap \text{Bd} B$.

I'm sorry, it might be a stupid question, but I did not understand how $A^{\circ} \cap \partial B$ and  $B^{\circ} \cap \partial A$ being empty directy imply that $a \in  \partial A \cap \partial B$

@FaustoMartinez I should've been more explicit. We have that $\text{Cl} A = \text{Int} A \cup \text{Bd} A$ and similarly for $\text{Cl} B$. Observe that $\text{Cl} A \cap \text{Cl} B = (\text{Int} A \cup \text{Bd} A) \cap (\text{Int} B \cup \text{Bd} B) = \underbrace{(\text{Int} A \cap \text{Int} B) \cup (\text{Int} A \cap \text{Bd} B) \cup (\text{Int} B \cap \text{Bd} A)} \cup (\text{Bd} A \cap \text{Bd} B)$, from set theory. Since the first three (underbraced) terms are all empty, then it follows that anything in $\text{Cl} A \cap \text{Cl} B$ must be in $\text{Bd} A \cap \text{Bd} B$.

Thank you very much
